# How does non-negative constrained optimization work?

Tags: optimization, logistic-regression

I am dealing with a machine learning problem in which a logistic regression model is trained with under-bound constrained optimization for model interpretability purposes.

In a simple 2-dimensional unconstrained case, let us assume that the loss function looks like below,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO1F5.jpg

Now, if we constrain this optimization to be an under-bound constrained optimization i.e., the weights can only be zero or positive, would this be equivalent to slicing the loss function at `y=0` such that instead of a single global minimum, would we end up with a truncated structure like below,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD0Y5.jpg

If we try to find the minimum of this constrained loss function, can we expect to see different values for `x` (from -2 to +2) since all those values are resulting in a minimum value for the loss function?

If this is true, how would this affect the performance of this model with different sets of weights? Would different weights of `x` have no impact on the performance of the model?

I read in one of [SO threads](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/23473/67278) that non-negative constrained optimization makes the search space smaller. Can anyone help me understand this better?

P.S: Apologies for posting links, I don't have enough reputation to post images